# How to run transformation on Json data format using python

Tags: python, json, md5

I am familiar with running data transformation using python on csv file format but new to running data transformation on Json format.

I have a Json streaming  data and I want to apply md5 algorithm to generate hash. I have created the function responsible for generating md5 hash, but I do not know how to apply this function to the json data

Here is my md5 hash generation script

```
import hashlib

# initializing string
Password= "kureen2022!"
AccountName = "ikire@gmail.com"


# Convert password to bytes
pw_byte = Password.encode()

# Generate Salt
salt = AccountName.lower().encode()  

# Concatenate salt with password, apply md5
result = hashlib.md5(salt+pw_byte)
pw_hash = result.hexdigest()

# printing Hash value.
print(pw_hash)
```

here is my Json script

```
import json

f = open('my_json.Json')

data = json.load(f)

for i in data['details']:
     print(i)
```

here is a sample json data

```
{
  "details" : [
   {
    "AccountName": "dojoujre",
     "Password": "password123"
    },
    {
    "AccountName": "dojoujre",
     "Password": "password007"
     }
  ]
}
```

The objective is to apply the md5 script to the json file
generate a hash

```
{
  "details" : [
   {
    "AccountName": "dojoujre",
     "Password": "password123",
     "Hash": "93837373930"
    },
    {
    "AccountName": "dojoujre",
     "Password": "password007",
     "Hash": "eer3er5t6t6y"
     }
  ]
}
```

would be glad for some direction.
Also if anyone can direct me to the right materials where I can learn how to perform data transformation with Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, JSON objects are handled just like dictionaries. Hence, your code shall be something similar to:

```py
for x in data['details']:
  x['Hash'] = compute_md5(x['Password'])
```

[Here is](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) the official doc about dictionaries.
Check out also [this doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) which has some useful functionalities to serialize/deserialize jsons.

A short notice about md5 hashing: I'd discourage you to use md5 to compute "security" hashes in a production and/or critical environment. Md5 algorithm is basically broken and if I recall correctly, a collision can be found with only 2^11 operations, which is very easy with modern computers. You should rely on much more secure algorithms such as SHA-3.

Comment: @Freerico Di Cesare, Thanks alot for this... very helpful.. between, what benefits does SHA-3 have over the other Hash algorithms

Comment: @lee its is quite a complex and long discussion. In a nutshell: it is harder to find another input which provides the very same hash output. However, I encourage you to look around in crypto.stackexchange or simply google it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like a dict and iterate over the list of dicts.

Access item with :

```
data.get('details') # or

data['details']
```

You can write a new entry with:

```
data['result'] = xxxx
```

I think that is what you are asking for, isn't?